# Species Scores not appearing from metaMDS

Tags: r, vegan

I'm not really sure what is happening considering it works on my computer at work, but doesn't transfer over when I'm on my laptop at home :/. For background, I am working with microbial community data using unifrac distances and trying to see how my different sample types cluster together.

Anywho, first I create a square distance matrix using my unifrac data file and my meta data.

```
generate.square.dist.matrix(unifrac,metadata,1)
unifrac.matrix.all = dist.matrix1
unifrac.dist.all = square.dist.matrix
```

Then run my NMDS

```
nmds.all = metaMDS(unifrac.dist.all, k = 4, trymax = 500, distance = "bray")
```

but when I attempt to extract my scores...

```
nmds.all.scores = as.data.frame(scores(nmds.all))
```

I receive the following error: "Error in x$species[, choices, drop = FALSE] :
incorrect number of dimensions".

Comment: You need to provide reproducible data and identify all relevant packages that you have loaded with `library()` commands. I cannot find any source for the function `generate.square.dist.matrix()` and your other commands seem to involve assignment using undefined objects, dist.matrix1 and square.dist.matrix.

Comment: I apologize. I am using vegan and ggplot2, and generate.square.dist.matrix() is a custom function. The answer below nipped it in the bud, thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

There is no reproducible example, but I can still reproduce this. There is a bug in `scores` function, and it fails when the `metaMDS` result object has no species scores. It will not have species scores if you supply dissimilarity matrix as input, because dissimilarities have no information  of species. I'll fix this in **vegan**. Meanwhile you can circumvent the problem by asking only site scores so that the function will not try to extract the non-existent species scores:

```
scores(nmds.all, display="site")
```

Comment: The bug is fixed now in github. The bug was introduced in release 2.6-2.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Rather new to the R world and I had a feeling it was something as simple as this.